# How to pass array/list of parameters to mvc controller method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, parameters, asp.net-mvc-5.1

I have a controller method like that:

```
 public async Task<IEnumerable<MyModel>> GetLinks(IList<string> links)
        {
        }
```

Is there anyway I can pass the params to that controller method form url like so:

`<endpoint>/getginks?links=http://link1&?links=http://link2` etc?

but for some reason I cant even pass a single param `<endpoint>/getginks?links=http://link1` 
In that case controller getting hit but `links = null`, I checked on debug.

is there anything I can do?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the array specification to the URL params, similar to if you were producing POST params from a view.

Try:

```
/getginks?links[0]=http://link1&links[1]=http://link2&links[2]=http://link3
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to encode your string and then pass it to your controller.

you can use ajax call, before submitting just encode it
    $.htmlEncode(links) 
with the use of jquery.html.encode.decode.js